# Type mismatch when trying to destructure type in Elm?

Tags: elm, type-mismatch

I have a type:

```
type MenuItem msg
    = MenuItem
        { attributes : List (Attribute msg)
        , children : List (Html msg)
        }
```

that's part of a `NavBar`. Then I have a function `renderItems` that renders a list of `MenuItem`s:

```
renderItems : List (MenuItem msg) -> Html msg
renderItems items =
    ul [ class "nav-list" ] (List.map renderItem items)
```

`renderItems`, as you can see,  calls `renderItem`, which looks like this:

```
renderItem : MenuItem msg -> Html msg
renderItem { attributes, children } =
    li [ class "nav-item" ]
        [ a ([ class "nav-link" ] ++ attributes)
            children
        ]
```

But I get a compiler error here:

```
This record is causing problems in this pattern match.

14| renderItem { attributes, children } =
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The pattern matches things of type:

    MenuItem msg

But the values it will actually be trying to match are:

    { c | attributes : a, children : b }

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

Can anyone interpret this for me? I don't understand the mismatch. `attributes` and `children` seem to match up pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type MenuItem msg
    = MenuItem
        { attributes : List (Attribute msg)
        , children : List (Html msg)
        }
```

is distinct from

```
type alias MenuItem msg
    = { attributes : List (Attribute msg)
      , children : List (Html msg)
      }
```

The latter can be pattern matched the way you did:

```
renderItem { attributes, children } =
```

but the former, since it is wrapped in a data constructor will also need to be unwrapped:

```
renderItem (MenuItem { attributes, children }) =
```