# Destructuring records in Elm with "as" word

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm doing the Elm exercises in [Exercism](https://exercism.org/tracks/elm/exercises/ticket-please) again and there's a thing unclear to me so far. How does the "as" destructuring work? In the beginning I didn't understand anything. After read Yang Wei's [Elm destructuring (or pattern matching) cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/yang-wei/4f563fbf81ff843e8b1e), more specifically this part:

```
myRecord = { x = 1, y = 2, z = 3}

computeSomething ({x, y} as wholeRecord) =
    -- x and y refer to the x and y fields of the passed in record
    -- wholeRecord is the complete record
    -- i.e. x and wholeRecord.x refer to the same field
    -- but z is only accessible as wholeRecord.z
```

A lot of things became more cleat to me. The problem happened when I tried to make it by myself. So, the [Ticket, Please!](https://exercism.org/tracks/elm/exercises/ticket-please) problem imports three types, called *Ticket*, *Status* and *User* and I should write a functions that receives a ticket and an user and returns a modified ticket, as the given example:

```
assignTicketTo (User "Danny")
    (Ticket
        { status = New
        , createdBy = ( User "Jesse", 3 )
        , assignedTo = Just (User "Alice")
        , comments = [ ( User "Jesse", "I've been waiting for 6 months!!" ) ]
        }
    )
-- => Ticket
--        { status = InProgress
--        , createdBy = ( User "Jesse", 3 )
--        , assignedTo = Just (User "Danny")
--        , comments = [ ( User "Jesse", "I've been waiting for 6 months!!" ) ]
--        }
```

The big problem comes here, because after descruture the *Ticket* variable and use *as* to attribute it to a different variable (as below), the language tells me that the new variable has a different type, i.e. it is not a *Ticket*.

```
assignTicketTo : User -> Ticket -> Ticket
assignTicketTo user ({ status, assignedTo } as ticket) =
    if (status == New) then
        { ticket | status = InProgress, assignedTo = Just user }
    else
        ticket
```

What am I doing wrong? I read the answer about [Type mismatch when trying to destructure type in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170319/type-mismatch-when-trying-to-destructure-type-in-elm), but the only thing that I can imagine I could possibly be doing wrong, the desctructuring, is not correct either:

```
assignTicketTo : User -> Ticket -> Ticket
assignTicketTo user (Ticket { status, assignedTo } as ticket) =
    if (status == New) then
        { ticket | status = InProgress, assignedTo = Just user }
    else
        ticket
```

**Edit:** The error messages are:

```
This is not a record, so it has no fields to update!

45|         Ticket { ticket | status = InProgress, assignedTo = Just user }
                     ^^^^^^
This `ticket` value is a:

    Ticket

But I need a record!
```

and

```
The 2nd argument to `assignTicketTo` is weird.

43| assignTicketTo user ({ status, assignedTo } as ticket) =
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The argument is a pattern that matches record values of type:

    { c | assignedTo : a, status : b }

But the type annotation on `assignTicketTo` says the 2nd argument should be:

    Ticket
```

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: You might need to return `Ticket { ticket | … }`

Comment: Good suggestion, but I get the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `Ticket` is not a record type. It's a custom type with a single variant containing a record. Its definition (which is essential context that you should have posted in the question) is:

```
type Ticket
    = Ticket
        { status : Status
        , createdBy : ( User, Int )
        , assignedTo : Maybe User
        , comments : List ( User, String )
        }
```

To destructure this you have to first unwrap the custom type, then unwrap the record and give just that a name:

```
Ticket ({ status, assignedTo } as ticket)
```

And then to return a `Ticket` again you also have to wrap the record back up in the `Ticket` constructor after updating it. The full working function therefore is:

```
assignTicketTo : User -> Ticket -> Ticket
assignTicketTo user (Ticket ({ status, assignedTo } as ticket)) =
    if status == New then
        Ticket { ticket | status = InProgress, assignedTo = Just user }

    else
        Ticket ticket
```

Why the `Ticket` type has been designed in this way I don't know. It seems unnecessarily convoluted and invites confusion. So please don't feel too bad about that!

Comment: Wonderful answer! So, the type definition is not given to us in the question. They make an automatic import into the code of those three types I said in the question. But now it's very clear, thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah that certainly doesn't make it any less confusing. I thought it might have been shown in an earlier exercise or in an introduction perhaps. I found it just by clicking though to Github. And I suppose it's also sort of evident from the usage example.

Comment: The idea behind wrapping a record in a single-variant custom type is that it protects the record from intervention outside the module it was defined in, as long as the said custom type is opaque (ie. does not export its constructor). That allows you to limit the allowable operations on the record by exporting specific functions from its module. Other modules can't mess with it and create broken states.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case here though, since this type is defined in another module and its internals expected to be used outside it. But that is usually the rationale for this pattern. Good point!